# how to make rows with a for-loop ??

Tags: java, php, for-loop

```
public class Arraymini {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        int [] testArray1= {1,6,3,9,2};
        double [] testArray2= {2.3, 8.66, 6.5, -9.2};

        printArray(testArray1);
        printArray(testArray2);
    }

    public static void printArray(int []k){
        for(int i=0; i<k.length; i++){
        System.out.println(k[i]+" ");
        }
    }

    public static void printArray(double[]g){
        for(int i=0; i<g.length; i++){
            System.out.println(g[i]+" ");
        }
    }

}
```

is their a way i am suppose to change the for-loop for it to print out in a row ????? when i run it in eclipse it prints in a straight line like : 1
                                                      6
                                                      3
                                                      2
                                                      2.3
                                                      8.66
                                                      6.5
                                                      -9.2 
i need it to print in rows seperated by spaces how would i do so ???

Comment: I compiled it and ran it through command prompt and it printed all the numbers in separate rows.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `printArrays` methods, do:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(testArray1));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(testArray2));
```